# How to pass loader options with Resolve.Alias

Tags: javascript, webpack-4

I want to pass options to 'raw-loader' while using alias since the use of loader ['base64-inline-loader' or 'raw-loader'] will be conditional for *.csv

```
if(condition) {
   require('raw-loader!files/file_name.csv'); //I want to add this "options: { esModule: false }"
} else {
   require('base64-inline-loader!files/file_name.csv');
}
```

Aliases,
I want to add this "options: { esModule: false }" to 'raw-loader' alias.

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      'base64-inline-loader': "base64-inline-loader",
      'raw-loader': "raw-loader"
    }
  }
```

Rules that are used for .csv if not calling with alias:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
        { /*Runs as default when not using alias*/
          test: /\.csv$/i,
          use: ['base64-inline-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.csv$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'raw-loader',
            options: {
              esModule: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      }]
```